# Perform multiple actions after wp_insert_user()

Tags: users, forms, user-registration

I have a custom registration form on my homepage, which runs wp_insert_user correctly.  However, after it has created the user, I need to perform the following actions:

- Log user in immediately
- Add item to cart
- Redirect to checkout

I think I know how to do the 2nd and 3rd item, but I cannot seem to get the automatic login to work as a first step.

Form Code:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="user_registeration">
   <label for="fname">First name:<span class="error">*</span></label><br>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">  

   <label for="lname">Last name:<span class="error">*</span></label><br>
   <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">

   <label for="phonenum">Phone Number:<span class="error">*</span></label><br>
   <input type="text" id="phone_num" name="phonenum">           

   <label>Email address <span class="error">*</span></label>
   <input type="text" name="user_email" class="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required /> 
                                           
   <label>Password <span class="error">*</span></label>
   <input type="password" name="password" class="text" placeholder="Enter Your password" required />
        
   <input  type="submit" name="user_registeration" value="NEXT">
```

Validation + insert user:

```
<?php if(isset($signUpError)){echo '<div>'.$signUpError.'</div>';}?>

<?php
   if (isset($_POST['user_registeration'])) {
    global $reg_errors;
    $reg_errors = new WP_Error;
    $firstname=$_POST['fname'];
    $middlename=$_POST['mname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lname'];
    $phonenum=$_POST['phone_num'];
    $useremail=$_POST['user_email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
                                
                                
    if( empty( $useremail ) || empty($password)) {
       $reg_errors->add('field', 'Required form field is missing');
    }    
    if ( !is_email( $useremail ) ) {
        $reg_errors->add( 'email_invalid', 'Email id is not valid!' );
    }
    if ( email_exists( $useremail ) ) {
       $reg_errors->add( 'email', 'Email Already exist!' );
    }
    if ( 5 > strlen( $password ) ) {
       $reg_errors->add( 'password', 'Password length must be greater than 5!' );
    }
                                
    if (is_wp_error( $reg_errors )) { 
       foreach ( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error )
   {
    
   $signUpError='<p style="color:#FF0000; text-aling:left;"><strong>ERROR</strong>: '.$error . '<br /></p>';
  } 
}
                                
if ( 1 > count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) ) {
   global $username, $useremail;
   $firstname  =   esc_attr( $_POST['fname'] );
   $middlename  =   esc_attr( $_POST['mname'] );
   $lastname  =   esc_attr( $_POST['lname'] );
   $useremail  =   sanitize_email( $_POST['user_email'] );
   $password   =   esc_attr( $_POST['password'] );
   $userdata = array(
     'user_login'    =>   $useremail,
     'user_email'    =>   $useremail,
     'user_pass'     =>   $password,
     'first_name'    =>   $firstname,
     'last_name'     =>   $lastname,
   );
   $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );


 }

} ?>
```

I tried adding this after the `$user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );` line:

```
   if(!is_wp_error($user)){
      wp_set_current_user($user); // set the current wp user
       wp_set_auth_cookie($user); // start the cookie for the current registered user

      //Add to cart and redirect - I HAVE TRIED REMOVING THIS, STILL DOESN'T LOGIN
      global $woocommerce;
      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      $product_id = 1086;
      $qty = 1;
      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$qty);
      return wc_get_checkout_url();
    }
```

And I also have tried hooking into the `user_register` action:

```
function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
  wp_set_current_user( $userid );
  wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );

  //Add to cart and redirect - I HAVE TRIED REMOVING THIS, STILL DOESN'T LOGIN
    global $woocommerce;
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    $product_id = 1086;
    $qty = 1;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id,$qty);
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

Neither option works.

Comment: using the `wp_set_current_user` and `wp_set_auth_cookie`, was the user logged in successfully?. try instead of `return wc_get_checkout_url();` to use `wp_redirect(wc_get_checkout_url())`. Don't use the user_register hook, try it with the first option

Comment: So did my answer help? How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`wp_set_auth_cookie()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/) will set cookies (using [`setcookie()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)) which means there must be no output (HTML, spaces, empty lines, etc.) sent to the browser yet, or otherwise, the cookies will not be set or updated.

And I said that because by the time you call [`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/), there has actually been an output sent to the browser, and the output is the whitespaces after the `?>` (PHP closing tag) in your code. For example, this part:

```php
<?php if(isset($signUpError)){echo '<div>'.$signUpError.'</div>';}?>

<?php
```

So the whitespaces after the `?>` are actually sent to the browser, hence that causes `setcookie()` to fail. Moreover, you've got an `echo` above which indicates you're not using the proper hook to auto-login (and redirect) the created user.

Therefore you should use an early hook such as [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) to create the user and then logs the user in, and finally do the redirect. Here's an example, just a basic one which hopefully would help you write your own or make your existing code works properly:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_387961' );
function wpse_387961() {
    // check if the form is submitted,
    // clean and validate user input,
    // define variables, etc etc.

    // ... your code.

    // create the user:
    $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    if ( ! $user || is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo 'try again later..';
        exit;
    }

    // auto-login the user:
    wp_set_current_user( $user );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user );

    // then ensure the user is successfully logged-in
    if ( (int) $user === get_current_user_id() ) {
        // add item to the cart
        // ... your code.

        // then do the redirect:
        wp_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
        exit;
    } else { // this 'else' part is just for testing
        echo 'auto-login failed?';
        exit;
    }
}
```

And actually, in your `auto_login_new_user()` function, the `$userid` is undefined (a typo, I guess?).. but anyway, you don't need to use the `user_register` hook. Just ensure and remember that when setting cookies via PHP and doing a redirect (using the PHP's native [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function which is used by `wp_redirect()`), do not output anything to the browser!